# How to execute the code after submitting the task to Hangfire in .NET Console App

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I have implemented Hangfire in .NET Console Application and It's working fine. After submitting Tasks(In my case downloading documents) to Hangfire I need to update the status of the Task(Document download status) in the Database, for this, I have the "UpdateDocumentStatus();" method but it never executed (Executing when entering something in the Console cmd window) as I have  Console.ReadKey(); in the program. If I remove  Console.ReadKey(); Hangfire not working.

Please suggest me alternative to  Console.ReadKey(); for Hangfire to execute my  "UpdateDocumentStatus();"

```
using System;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.MemoryStorage;

namespace HangFire
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();

            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => DownloadDocument());

            using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
            {
                Console.ReadKey(); //Need alternative to this line to execute below code
            }

            UpdateDocumentStatus();
        }

        public static void DownloadDocument()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading documents...");
        }

        public static void UpdateDocumentStatus()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Update status...");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Hangfire is a Queue based system. All tasks are executed in a background process. This requires the server to be running constantly to pick the jobs up.

Next, you need to understand what `using` does. Using gives scope to your objects. This means that at the end of your using statement, the object gets disposed.

In your case,

- BackgroundJobServer starts
- Read key
- dispose BackgroundJobServer

As long as you don't push a key, you remain inside the using statement and your server stays active (undisposed). That's why, when you remove 'Console.ReadKey();' your server does nothing as it gets disposed almost immediately.

For you the fix is basically: Remove the using block.

```
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();
       BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => DownloadDocument());
       var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
       UpdateDocumentStatus();
       Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin for your response.

Comment: @Srinivas did it solve your problem, or had you already solved it yourself?